# Bootstrap table make one column the full width of the row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table

Let's say I had the following table in bootstrap:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr><th>Title</th></tr> 
  <tr>
    <th>Heading</th>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

I would like to make sure the `Title` column its full width, meaning the size of the `Heading` and `Value` columns combined, or in other words, the size of the whole row.

I've tried this but without any luck:

```
<tr><th style="width: 100%">Title</th></tr>
```

How can make sure the `Title` isn't the size of an ordinary column, but the size of the whole row instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `colspan` attribute, like so:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
     <th colspan=“2”>Title</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading</th>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```